# How to make animation working right after button.click?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I need to animate a button just right after clicking on it. So I've made a simple animation AnimationDrawable:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_box" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_box_end" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

The only difference between gradient_box и gradient_box_end is the width (280 and 180dp correspondingly):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <size
    android:width="280dp"
    android:height="50dp"/>
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FF3366"
        android:endColor="#FF3366"
        android:angle="180"/>
    <padding android:left="7dp"
        android:top="7dp"
        android:right="7dp"
        android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="35dp" />
</shape>
```

Button has android:background="@drawable/gradient_animation" assigned in xml layuot.

MainActivity.cs is:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

      SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

      Button buttonlogin = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1); //animated button
      AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable)buttonlogin.Background;


      buttonlogin.Click += (sender, e) =>
      {
        animation.Start();
      };
```

The problem is that animation works after some actions with the application but not just after button.click. For example, I click a button, nothing happens, I click on a edittext, keyboard appears on a screen and animation starts.

I have found that google recommends this:

> It's important to note that the start() method called on the AnimationDrawable cannot be called during the onCreate() method of your Activity, because the AnimationDrawable is not yet fully attached to the window. If you want to play the animation immediately, without requiring interaction, then you might want to call it from the onWindowFocusChanged() method in your Activity, which will get called when Android brings your window into focus.

But after some attempts I still cannot find a solution.

Comment: I think you should make `AnimationDrawable animation (AnimationDrawable)buttonlogin.Background;` inside Button clicklistener

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple i would like to suggest a library https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations 
try it as it is simple to use and have many varieties of animation to choose from .

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ASo57cTVctM) is a simple example of using [Translate Animation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) all of just you need to manage these with Animation Class object just like below create object in onCreate.

```
Animation traslateAnimation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, 
R.anim.yourxmlanimation);
```

and use this code inside button onclick

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

  v.startAnimation(traslateAnimation)
  }
});
```